# Searchable List of Different Datatypes

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm working on an application that displays different customized form controls to users depending on the data type of the value that needs to be displayed. So, for example, a Boolean value appears as a check box. However, there are some types that I do not want to display. As the form and controls are generated at run-time, I need to build some logic that prevents these unsupported types from appearing.

Here's what I've tried to accomplish this:

I have a List `unsupportedTypes As List(Of Type)` that I fill with the types I want to exclude:

```
unsupportedTypes.Add(GetType(System.Drawing.Color))
'more types removed for brevity
```

This complies, but throws a null reference exception at the above line, which I suppose makes sense since there isn't any *thing* to put into the list. However, trying to create a color

```
unsupportedTypes.Add(GetType(New System.Drawing.Color))
```

will not even compile.

How can I build a list (or other collection) of different data types that I can search?

Comment: This compiles and works, so i don't understand your issue:

    `Dim unsupportedTypes As New List(Of Type)
    unsupportedTypes.Add(GetType(Drawing.Color))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles and works at runtime, so i don't really understand your issue:

```
Dim unsupportedTypes As New List(Of Type)  ' New prevents a null reference exception
unsupportedTypes.Add(GetType(Drawing.Color))
```

Since you have mentioned `i have a list: unsupportedTypes As List(Of Type)`, is it possible that you have forgotten to initialize it?

Comment: Oh. My. God. The missing New was the problem. Thanks! I really shouldn't be coding at 7am.